# How do I loop through a list of li tags having same class and change their corresponding styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I have a list of li tags having same class and and i want to change
>   their styles and their children elements styles when ever a user hover
>   over each the li which is the container, below is the code I have
>   tried. I used getElementsByClassName to get the node list of all li
>   tags, now, what I want to do is add event listener to each one of them
>   and manipulate the style of each when ever a user triggers a mouseover
>   event

```js
function doFirst(){
    var playList = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
    var play = document.getElementsByClassName("play");
    var plus = document.getElementsByClassName("plus");
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName("title");

    function songHover (e){
        playList[0].style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
        play[0].style.display = "block";
        plus[0].style.display = "block";
        title[0].style.width = "50%";
    }
    function songHoverOut (e){
        playList[0].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        play[0].style.display = "none";
        plus[0].style.display = "none";
        title[0].style.width = "auto";
    }
    playList[0].addEventListener("mouseover", songHover, false);
    playList[0].addEventListener("mouseleave", songHoverOut, false);

}
window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

```css
content .song-list{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
content .song-list ul{
    margin-bottom:4%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
content .song-list ul > p{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6% 0 1% 0;
    font-size: 140%;
    color: #2b32b2;
}
content .song-list ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    padding: 2%;
}
.title{
    border: 0px solid red;
    flex:1;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.title h4{
    font-weight: normal!important;
    font-size: 98%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
.title p{
    font-size: 85%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.title p:first-child{
    flex:1;
}
.title p:last-child{
    max-width: 50%;
}
content .song-list ul li i{
    display: none;
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3.8% 0;
}
.play{

}
.plus{

}
.duration{
    display: block;
    border: 0px solid red;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3.8% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="song-list">
  <ul>
      <p>A</p>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>A Sky Full Of Stars</h4>
              <p>Coldplay</p>
              <p>Ghost Stories</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">4:28</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>The A Team (george.ortha@ferialaw.com)</h4>
              <p>Ed Sheeran</p>
              <p>+</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">4:18</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Adore You</h4>
              <p>miley Cyrus</p>
              <p>bangerz</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">4:38</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Adorn (george.ortha@ferialaw.com)</h4>
              <p>Miguel</p>
              <p>Kaleidoscope Dream</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">3:13</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Again</h4>
              <p>Fetty Wrap</p>
              <p>Billboard Hot 100 Singles Chart</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">5:12</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <p>B</p>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>
              Back to December (george.ortha@ferialaw.com)
              </h4>
              <p>Tailor Swift</p>
              <p>2011 Billboard Chart</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">4:43</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Bad (george.ortha@ferialaw.com)</h4>
              <p>Wale</p>
              <p>The Gifted</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">4:14</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Bad Blood</h4>
              <p>Tailor Swift</p>
              <p>2011 Billboard Chart</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">5:12</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Bartender</h4>
              <p>Lady Antebellum</p>
              <p>747</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">5:12</span>
      </li>
      <li class="list">
          <span class="title">
              <h4>Believe Me</h4>
              <p>Lil Wayne</p>
              <p>Believe Me</p>
          </span>
          <i class="play">></i>
          <i class="plus">+</i>
          <span class="duration">5:12</span>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I found some information that [may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111854/javascript-addeventlistener-on-all-created-li-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that simpler solution is css `:hover` pseudo class (change styles when user hovers element with cursor).

Example: `.parent:hover .some-child {hover styles}`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a bit confused about the "addEventListener". You do not have to add an event listener to the window to initialize the code. Simply wrap it in a `(function(){ // Your code })();` and it will execute as soon as possible.

But here you have an jsfiddle about how you could go about it: https://jsfiddle.net/g59x59rr/12/

Though, I used "querySelectorAll" instead of "getElementsByClassName". But I hope my solution will make sense to you. :)

```js
(function() {
  var lielem = document.querySelectorAll(".li"), i;
  for (i = 0; i < lielem.length; i++) {
     lielem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      this.style.color = 'red';
      this.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
       this.style.color = 'black';
      });
    });
  }
})();
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li">First Li</li>
  <li class="li">Second Li</li>
  <li class="li">Third Li</li>
</ul>
```